# Is there a way to just make the first character a different color using iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am using itext7 with C# and I just want to use a paragraph and the first character needs to be a different color. Is there any way to do it? In iText5 there was a thing with chunks but this is not available in iText7 so I am stuck at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no chunks, but you can add to Paragraph strings with different characteristics.

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    string original = "Some text";

    string first = original.Substring(0, 1);

    p.Add(new Text(first)
            .SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE));
    p.Add(original.Substring(1, original.Length - 1));
    doc.Add(p);
    doc.Close();
```

This should create a PDF file where "ome text" is in black, but "S" is in blue.

Relevant documentation ([Colored Text example](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/colored-text)) and the API for [Paragraph](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_paragraph.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, that is also a great way of doing it!
I was just about to post a solution I came up with while almost destroying my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a **Text** to a **Paragraph** and set the color before adding it to the **Paragraph**.

```
var dotstring = new Text("$");
var cashstring = new Text("1.000,-");
dotstring.SetFontColor(DeviceCmyk.MAGENTA);

var NummerParagraph = new Paragraph();
NummerParagraph.Add(dotstring);
NummerParagraph.Add(cashstring);
```

This is an easy solution I found since my first letter is static, I know what it is.
The other solution posted by **André Lemos** is way better if you don't know the first letter of the string.